# jsPDF - Angular: HTML to PDF

Tags: angular, jspdf

[image: This is the HTML]

After I used jsPDF for generating pdf the whatsApp image looks like this in the pdf[image]

The code for converting image to base64 is as follows:

```
    getBase64Image(img) {
    console.log("=================", img);
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    console.log("image", canvas);
    debugger;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    return dataURL;
  }
```

Further jsPDF code is as follows:

```
const pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'a4', true);
    pdf.internal.scalefactor = 1.5;
    pdf.addHTML(document.getElementById('toPdfs'), () => {
        debugger;

        if(this.volumegraphImage) {
            this.volumegraphImageData = this.getBase64Image(document.getElementById("graph1"));
            pdf.addImage(this.volumegraphImageData, "jpg", 50, 110, 200, 100);
        }}
```

I also tried using the below code, but in vain.

```
pdf.addImage(this.volumegraphImageData, "jpg", 50, 110, 200, 100, null, 'FAST');
```

I'm using jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js version of jdPDF and html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.js.

How can I display whatsapp image in the pdf(image 2) as it is in the html page(image 1)?

Comment: Alright, I looked up the documentation, and found the solution.

In my getBase64Image(img) function instead of just writing       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      write         
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height) ;